# How does motion of consciousness beings fit into Newton's laws?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Newton's first law says that a body which has no external forces acting on it should not change it's direction of motion, yet somehow, without any external effects to me, I move my fingers over my keyboard to type this question. This seems to be a contradiction with the first law.

How would we resolve this seeming paradox?

Comment: Sorry but I am voting to close because it is not a Physics question (plus, it simply does not make sense).

Comment: And, how does it not make sense? And in what sense is not a physics question? @Quillo  I would very much apprecite you to englithen me, as I thought I had the ability for knowing what constitutes as on after spending years on this site.

Comment: It has nothing to do with consciousness. Moreover, you are an extended system (interacting with the environment). Given the subsystem "fingers", the muscles (plus all the constraints due to the bones) impart an external force on them.

Comment: "without any external effects to me" - if you type for long enough, you'll need food from an external source.

Comment: Well, I suppose any being which has some form of consciousness would be able to perform such a task. With no apparent external force on them, they'd be able to undergo motion of the limb. Hence, the title. @Quillo

Comment: It seems strange to me to talk about consciousness in this case. How about an excavator? They have a sort of arm with pistons (muscles) and rigid parts with junctions (bones). Maybe, in the end, you could edit your question along the line of "how does Newton' law apply to machines"?

Comment: I'd imagine an excavator has some motors and so to have it moved in a directed way @Quillo

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are floating freely in space and not touching anything, your centre of gravity does not move when you type. When you move the muscles in your arm to extend your finger, the shape of your body changes. That is all.

If your finger presses the keyboard with a force of a gram of so then the keyboard presses your finger with a force of a gram or so and the centre of gravity of your whole body moves accordingly.

Comment: And wouldn't the shape of my body changing indicate a presence of force? Clearly the particles that make it up would have to move in space for such a thing to happen

Comment: But those are internal forces. They don't change your velocity.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's laws say that a body changes its velocity when forces act on it. This applies to conscious bodies as well as any other.

You and I are able to create forces. Nobody understands the mechanism of consciousness. But we do know that our brains generate nerve impulses that travel to muscles and make them contract.

Questions of what consciousness is and how it works are beyond the scope of known physics. But I hope someday we learn more and will be able to explain it. I am not holding my breath.

---

If I was floating in space, I would be able to move my arms and legs. But my total motion would be a straight line at constant velocity. Momentum is conserved. This means if I move one body part one direction, other body parts must move in the opposite direction.

If I am near an external object, I can push it away. Newton's laws say that every force has an equal and opposite reaction. This means that if I push on an external object, the external object pushes back on me. That is an external force. Both the object and I change velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Let's change the scale of things a little bit, and consider reaching forwards with your right arm to press a big very stiff button on the wall.

You are sitting on a swivel chair. As you move your arm forward towards the button (without actually touching it), your body and the chair rotate a little to the right. Move your arm back in, and you rotate back to the original position.

Now repeat that and try to push the big stiff button. **It doesn't move**. Instead, your body and the chair rotate even further to the right. Now, when you withdraw your arm, you again rotate to the left *but not back to the original position*. The external reaction supplied by pressing against the button has now affected your position.

Next, replace the swivel chair with a fixed chair. Now you can reach out and press the button successfully. Why? Because of the external force supplied by friction, between the chair and the floor.